# I think this is an awkwardly broken sewer cleanout cap...if so how to remove and replace?

Tags: sewer, cleanout

This is just outside the door to the laneway house and was broken after being stepped on and after doing some googling it looks like it's the sewer cleanout cap which is now broken awkwardly. I tried unscrewing it by hand but couldn't get it out. Any tips as to how I can remove it?

Should any 4 inch cap replacement work (it says 100 cm or 4 inches on the pipe)?

Also the plastic that was on top that broke off has fallen down the pipe - do I need to worry about that?

Thanks in advance!!

[image]

Comment: that is going to hurt you

Comment: Is it a thread-on cap?  You might want to stuff a towel or something down there, then bash the rest of it apart and vacuum out the bits.

Comment: Gasp the remaining part of the cap with a suitably gloved hand and try to turn it ACW. If that does not work, then attack with tools but only AFTER blocking the drain with a large towel or large mass of paper. It would be too easy to lose grip on some pliers, a saw or a chisel.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do much about the plastic that has fallen down.

It could be the responsibility of you Council or Authority.

If not, then note the marking on the pipe and ask the store for a compatible cap.  There is also some writing on the cap which could help in its replacement.  Both are hard to read on the image.

Down here, water and sewage use different grades of pipes.  I suspect, that at most there will be two standards in your area.  As long as you look for a cap for a sewage grade pipe, you should be fine.